# can't specify runtime for heroku local

Tags: python, heroku

I am running **heroku local** to start an app, and I want to specify python runtime as mentioned [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes)

```
cat runtime.txt
python-3.7.2
```

however, when i run *heroku local*, it still used the python 2:

```
8:57:40 PM web.1    |  APP     runtime version: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Comment: Please show the content of `runtime.txt`

Comment: I'd be very surprised if `runtime.txt` did anything locally. Instead, use a virtualenv with the correct version of Python.